# Should a class verify that private members exist before using them?

Tags: oop, constructor, language-agnostic

Is it a good idea to always verify that private members of a class exist before methods use them?

Consider this example:

```
class Game() {
  constructor() {
    this._setupCamera();
    this._updateCameraPosition();
  }

  _setupCamera() {
    this._camera = new Camera();
  }

  _updateCameraPosition() { 
    this._camera.position.x = 500;
  }
}
```

If the order of calls in the constructor are rearranged, the class will break because the camera is not defined yet.

The example seems silly but I run into this frequently with larger classes. The order of initialization in the constructor becomes important but, without checking for private members, nothing enforces the order of calls.

I can avoid the problem like so:

```
_updateCameraPosition() {
  if (!this._camera) {
    throw new Error('Camera is not defined!');
  }

  this._camera.position.x = 500;
}
```

Is it a good idea to always check if a private member is defined before using it?

Answer (score 2):

As a rule of thumb, you can't make any assertions about an object's state - object's (private) fields - until the `constructor` has finished it's run; such behavior is simply undefined, at least in Java.

So, answering your question, the best practice might be to initialize the members in constructor, and then make modifications to the in post-construction methods. In complex classes you might want to use Factory design pattern.

Or be absolutely sure to write the constructor's implementation in the right order :)

Answer (score 0):

**"Is it a good idea to always check if a private member is defined before using it?"**

Yes. Moreover, it is a common practice to expose member variables as properties and use [lazy instantiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_initialization).

```
private _myWidget;

private property MyWidget
{
  get
  {
    if (_myWidget == null)
      _myWidget = new Widget();

    return _myWidget;    
  }

  set
  {
    _myWidget = value;
  }
}
```

If the setter is never called, a Widget is created on the fly in the getter if the private member variable is found to be null.